# How to handle HTTP status code in Spring Webclient

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

I'm stuck trying to do simple error handling when calling a remote service. The service returns a Map. The behaviour I'm looking for is:

- HTTP 200 --> Return body (`Map<String, String>`).
- HTTP 500 --> Throw a particular exception
- HTTP 404 --> Simply return `Null`.

Here's my code:

```
private Map<String, String> loadTranslations(String languageTag) {
    try {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(serviceUrl);
        Map<String, String> result = webClient.get()
            .uri("/translations/{language}", languageTag)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(httpStatus),
                clientResponse -> Mono.error(new MyServiceException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)))
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> Mono.error(new MyServiceException(response.statusCode())))
            .bodyToMono(Map.class)
            .block();

        return result;
    } catch (MyServiceException ex) {  // doesn't work as in reality it throws ReactiveException
        ....
    }
}
```

I don't know how to have the result of block() return NULL (or something that I can interpret as "404 was received"). The idea would be to just return NULL on 404 and throw an exception on 500.

I tried returning Mono.empty() but in that case the `result` variable contains the body of the response as Dictionary (I'm using standard Spring error bodies that contain `timestamp`, `path`, `message`).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: I currently have this same problem, will report back if I find a solution.  Pretty sure there should be an idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: for 404 case you can return `onStatus(httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(httpStatus),
clientResponse -> Mono.empty())`  and then check if the value of one key inside the map is null. and if that is the case return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResponseSpec` class's `onStatus` method signature from Spring WebFlux 5.x

```
ResponseSpec onStatus(Predicate<HttpStatus> statusPredicate,
                Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> exceptionFunction);
```

changed to

```
ResponseSpec onStatus(Predicate<HttpStatusCode> statusPredicate,
                Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> exceptionFunction);
```

in Spring Web 6.x

May be while upgrading to JDK 17 you upgraded spring version as well.

So change `HttpStatus::isError` to `HttpStatusCode::isError` and the error should go away.